# LibXML : colon in removeAttribute and value in getAttribute

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2, xml-libxml

This is my xml file

```
 <config xmlns:xc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <outer1  xmlns="http://blablabla">
      <inner1>
        <name>Hello</name>
        <org>wwf</org>
        <profession>warrior</profession>
      </inner1>
    </outer1>
  </config>
```

I want to do two things

1. Get the attribute value from config and outer1
2. Delete the attribute

This is the perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = "Sample3.xml";

my $parser =XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree   =$parser->parse_file($xml);
my $root   =$tree->getDocumentElement;
print $root->getAttribute('xmlns:xc'), "\n";
print $root->getAttribute('/config/outer1/@xmlns'), "\n"; --> not working

$root->removeAttribute('xmlns:xc');--> not working
print "$tree->toString";
```

The output should be

```
<config>
        <outer1>
          <inner1>
            <name>Hello</name>
            <org>wwf</org>
            <profession>warrior</profession>
          </inner1>
        </outer1>
      </config>
```

I managed to get the value of xmlns:xc but not for xmlns. I tried the other way with `$root->findvalue('/config/outer1/@xmlns');` but still not returning the value of xmlns. The other problem is removeAttribute. It doesn't recognize colon inside xmlns:xc but it does in getAttribute. I dont get why

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove XML namespaces with XML::LibXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756926/remove-xml-namespaces-with-xmllibxml)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use namepsaces with [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), use [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::XPathContext):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( string =>
'<config xmlns:xc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <outer1  xmlns="http://blablabla">
      <inner1>
        <name>Hello</name>
        <org>wwf</org>
        <profession>warrior</profession>
      </inner1>
    </outer1>
  </config>');

my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new;
$xpc->registerNs('b', 'http://blablabla');

say for $xpc->findnodes('/config/b:outer1', $xml);
#                               ^^^
```

Comment: When I modified to my $source = "Sample3.xml";
my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( string => $source); why do i get this ':1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
Sample3.xml
^'?

Comment: And also I will use the same code to other xml file with more than 19000 lines. I dont think I can directly put the xml content inside the code

Comment: @user3922604, You can keep using `parse_file` (I prefer that interface). If you want to use `load_xml`, it's `XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $qfn )` to load from a file

Comment: @ikegami : Thanks but what I want to delete is only the attribute not the node. And I still dont understand the different behaviour between removeAttribute and getAttribute in argument acceptance

Comment: @user3922604 did you try the linked answer?

Comment: @user3922604, I don't know why it works with getAttribute. It shouldn't.

Comment: Surprisingly, you can get the namespace, too: `$xpc->findnodes('/config/b:outer1', $xml))[0]->getAttribute('xmlns')`

Comment: Not surprising. It is an attribute, even though it is meta. Did you actually check if it could be deleted when you posted your answer?

Comment: The real question is how to delete change the namespace of the elements to the default namespace, and this doesn't answer that.

Comment: @dsolimano : yes, i tried and still figuring out how it works. I am new at Perl and LibXML

Comment: @ikegami : yes I can delete the namespace when i remove the colon

Comment: You can use `$outer->setNamespaceDeclURI(q(), q());` to remove a namespace from a node and its children.

Comment: @choroba : thanks, i tried this way my $xml2 = "Sample3.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree   =$parser->parse_file($xml2);


my $root   =$tree->getDocumentElement; $root->setNamespaceDeclURI(q(), q());
print "$tree->toString"; But it does nothing. Do we have something like XMLin in LibXML which ignores attributes?

Comment: @user3922604: The root is not in any namespace. `$root->setNamespaceDeclURI('xc', q());` removes the declaration from the root.

Comment: You must have a newer libxml2 than I do. (I have 2.7.8.) Neither `removeAttribute` nor any usage of `setNamespaceDecl*` removed the `xmlns`. Could you complete the answer and show how to remove the namespaces, please?

Comment: @ikegami: libxml2 version 2.9.2, XML::LibXML 2.0117

Comment: @user3922604, I just ran that question on  your code, and it works.  I'll post the code as an answer, but please don't vote up or accept it, instead close this question as a dupe of yours

Answer (score 0):

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $xml);
my $context = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $dom->documentElement() );
$context->registerNs( 'u' => '"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0' );
$context->registerNs( 'u' => 'http://alcatel-lucent.com/lte/enb');

for my $node ( $context->findnodes('//u:inner1[1]') ) {
 my ($mh)   = $context->findnodes('u:name', $node);
    $mh ->removeChildNodes();
    $mh->appendText('World123');
    print $dom->toString;
```

@Choroba : I got it. It should be $mh not $context. Thanks for your suggestion. And one more, why should put my ($mh) instead of my $mh?
@all: Thanks for the advice too